# Transform set of data into a single column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have this set of integers enclosed in the parenthesis (1,2,3,4,5).

Data I have:

```
(1,2,3,4,5)
```

And I would want them to be in a single column.

Expected Output:

```
 column 
--------
      1
      2
      3
      4
      5
(5 rows)
```

How can I do this? I've tried using array then unnest but with no luck. I know I'm doing something wrong.
I need this to optimize a query that is using a large IN statement, I want to put it in a temp table then join it on the main table.

Comment: `select * from unnest(array[1,2,3,4,5]);` but there is no need to put this into a temp table, you can join directly to the result of an `unnest()`

Comment: Thanks but the data i have is enclosed in the parentheses (1,2,3,4,5) so this does not work

Comment: Another question related to the main question. I think I'll get the result if I can get this data into an array.  This (1,2,3,4,5) to this {1,2,3,4,5}. The parenthesis is giving me headaches. I can easily do that without the parenthesis but alas its what the application throws at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the string to an array, then do the unnest:

```
select *
from unnest(translate('(1,2,3,4,5)', '()', '{}')::int[]);
```

The `translate()` call converts `'(1,2,3,4,5)'` to `'{1,2,3,4,5}'` which is the string representation of an array. That string is then cast to an array using `::int[]`.

You don't need a temp table, you can directly join to the result of the unnest.

```
select *
from some_table t 
  join unnest(translate('(1,2,3,4,5)', '()', '{}')::int[]) as l(id) 
    on t.id = l.id;
```

Another option is to simply use that array in a where condition:

```
select *
from some_table t
where t.id = any (translate('(1,2,3,4,5)', '()', '{}')::int[]);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is  exactly what I need.